# How to obtain a good execution plan for (LIKE @p) when the pattern is of the form 'prefix%'

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I'm using an ORM that executes queries of the form:

```
SELECT Columns
FROM T
WHERE Col LIKE @p0 ESCAPE '~'
```

`Col` is indexed and the index is covering. The predicate is very selective. The tables has 500,000 rows.

I'm always querying for a string prefix (e.g. `'prefix%'`). Clearly, this is not statically known to SQL Server here. But I know that SQL Server is basically capable of seeking based on a `LIKE` pattern with a prefix.

I would like SQL Server to discover at execution time the relevant range of the index to scan and only scan that range. The execution plan that I'm getting has an index scan, though.

The ORM does not support `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` and I'm not sure it would be a good option since the queries execute in about 20 milliseconds. (However I would like this query to go faster. With a seek this should be able to run in ~1ms).

Can I somehow make SQL Server perform a seek here?

Comment: Does your ORM support stored procedures? Why are you using an ORM that ties your hands behind your back?

Comment: @AaronBertrand Because the domain is very complex and the ORM makes refactorings quite reliable and easy. We value those properties in this particular code base. The ORM does support procs and direct SQL but this loses the ORM benefits. This issue appears about a dozen times throughout the app. I would not like to insert SQL into all those places.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I would like SQL Server to discover at execution time the relevant
>   range of the index to scan and only scan that range.

This is exactly the plan I get.

```
CREATE TABLE T(Columns VARCHAR(50), 
               Col VARCHAR(50), 
               INDEX IX(Col, Columns));

DECLARE @p0 VARCHAR(50) = 'foobar%'

SELECT Columns
FROM T
WHERE Col LIKE @p0 ESCAPE '~'
```

[image]

See [Dynamic Seeks and Hidden Implicit Conversions](http://web.archive.org/web/20170303101108/http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2012/01/18/dynamic-seeks-and-hidden-implicit-conversions.aspx) for more about this.

Check that the index is indeed covering and that the datatype of the parameter is correct for the column definition (i.e. if the column is `varchar` and the parameter is `nvarchar` this can cause a scan).

Comment: This is exactly what I want. I now have some homework to do to find out why this is not being produced in my case.

Comment: @boot4life if the index is definitely covering and there is no varchar vs nvarchar conversion please provide a repro if possible or at least create table with all relevant indexes and collations.

Comment: I found it through trial and error now. This index is filtered on `Col IS NOT NULL` and my query was `WHERE Col LIKE @p0 ESCAPE '~' AND Col IS NOT NULL`. I added this additional (redundant) `IS NOT NULL` to help the optimizer recognize the index because in the past I had trouble with filtered index matching. Turns out that here it prevents this important optimization. Looks like an optimizer limitation. Also, I realize I should have included the filtered index information in the question. It seemed irrelevant to me at that time.